# R + Applying function on multiple columns , while creating new columns, by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I searched for similar cases here, but did not found the right one. They are all slightly different.
Consider following data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2),col1=c(1:4),col2=c(2:5),col3=c(3:6))
```

What I need is to create in the same dt, 3 new difference columns for each columns, group by id.
I tried it with:

```
changeCols <- c("col1","col2","col3")
newCols <- paste0(changeCols, "_diff")
dt[,(newCols):=lapply(.SD, changeCols-shift(changeCols)),by=id, .SDCols=changeCols]
```

But the syntax seems to be wrong.

Appriciate any help!

Comment: Try dt[, (newCols) := .SD - shift(.SD), by=id, .SDcols=changeCols]

Comment: ... and use `.SDcols` instead of `.SDCols`.

Comment: now I faced additional issue: When I do: `dt[, if (.SD[2]>0) .SD[-1] else .SD, by=id, .SDcols=newCols]`, I lose changeCols, how to get the complete dt?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You might want to post a new question

Comment: You are right, I've posted a new question- thanks a lot for support!